# How to build ursina project via nuitka?

Tags: python, ursina, panda3d, nuitka

I'm trying to build my ursina project with Nuitka, but it doesn't work, what should I do? Can you please attach the command?

Comment: Please provide more details in your question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the tutorial here:
https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka
About halfway down the page is "Tutorial Setup and build on Windows."

If you are still needing help, please be more specific about what you have tried and what is failing.